# What approach to use on sentence classifier? - distant supervision

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, information-retrieval, feature-extraction, information-extraction

I am following approach of Distance supervision in article [Distant Supervision for Relation Extraction using Ontology Class Hierarchy-Based Features](http://2014.eswc-conferences.org/sites/default/files/eswc2014pd_submission_58.pdf).

I have already tokenized sentence for example:

> Her most famous temple, the Parthenon, on the Acropolis in Athens takes its name from that title

and I also have lexical features from this sentence as you can see in table:

[image]

The question is how to create feature vector from this table, which can be passed to Logistic regression? Or is there any other classification method, which should be used?

Answer (score 0):

A posible approach could be to use embeddings(for example word2vect). Example:
[Embeddings article from tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/word2vec/index.html)